# GCC and Makefile (multiple declarations of a function, even with only one?)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Currently trying to use GCC on Debian, along with a makefile since I am making one of my headers. Whenever I try to "make" the makefile, I get an error as follows:

> setup.o: In function 'setup':
>
> setup.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `setup'
>
> finalkek.o:finalkek.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [projExec] Error 1

My makefile looks like this:

```
projExec: finalkek.o setup.o
    gcc -o projExec finalkek.o setup.o

finalkek.o: finalkek.c setup.h
    gcc -c finalkek.c

setup.o: setup.c
    gcc -c setup.c
```

`finalkek.c` is my main file, and `setup` is my header.

In my main file, here is the only time I mention it:

```
include "setup.h" // Using the double quotes for a custom header...

void main()
{

setup();

       rest of code here...

}
```

In my header file, `setup.h`, I have it like this:

```
void setup()
{

      rest of code here...

}
```

Comment: Why do you have your implementation of your `setup()` function in `setup.h`? What's in `setup.c`? (is it some typo?).  Your problem is probably a multiple import error. We can provide a definite answer if you make the appropriate edits.

Comment: Though it's not related to the problem, `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you have a book or tutorial that told you to use `void main()`, find a better one whose author knows C.

Comment: Also, I edited out "Debian" both from the title and tag as it is almost surely irrelevant. Plus, please post all code (including makefiles) inside the post itself and not as screenshot

Comment: @KyrSt Will do, just need to take it from nano.

Comment: @KyrSt Well, looking at Keith's comment, I thought, maybe I'm not setting up my .c file for the .h correctly. Turns out I wasn't. Fixed it now. Should I edit with a solution?

Comment: @TrickyWitch Actually it is better to post it as an answer and accept it yourself.

Comment: `void setup() {` should be in setup.c, not setup.h

Answer (score 1):

A few things I noticed: Although technically allowed, it's flawed practice to implement the entire function in a header file. Header files are just for the prototypes (i.e. `void setup(void);` instead of the whole `void setup(void) { ... }`). What is in your setup.c? Also, Make isn't supposed to work like this.

```
finalkek.o: finalkek.c setup.h
    gcc -c finalkek.c
```

You shouldn't compile a header file directly, as it's not supposed to have actual implementations in it, just the prototypes. That's what the preprocessor does, with the directive `#include`, it takes the whole content of the specified header, and just puts it right there in the C file. So by telling Make to compile setup.h, you are including the content of that file in your project twice, which is probably giving you the error.

Like others have said, move your actual code for the function `setup()` to setup.c, as is appropriate. setup.h should look like this:

```
#ifndef SETUP_H
#define SETUP_H

void setup(void);

#endif
```

The lines `#ifndef SETUP_H, #define SETUP_H`, and `#endif`, are a formatting tool for header files, that keep you from including the same file more than once.

And then the accompanying setup.c:

```
#include "setup.h"

void setup(void) {
    // your code here
}
```

finalkek.c:

```
int main(void) {
    setup();

    // rest of code here
}
```